# How to run a work items query for/on previous state of closed item in TFS

Tags: tfs

I just want to run a query in TFS, to get a list of work items which are currently in closed state. where the condition is  & .

Eg: If item A is finished coding and been assigned to person X for review with 'In code Review' as state, and later the item A went through all the states and is closed.

So, now can I run a TFS query to get the list of closed items like A which were reviewed by person X?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to go into Team Explorer and from the Home screen (TFS 2012) select New Query under Work Items. From there, you can change the project or work item type you want to query on. You can also add other fields to search on as well as defining how they are joined together (and/or). You should be able to look through the fields and query on what you are looking for.

If memory serves, you should be able to access similar functionality in previous TFS versions (2008 and 2010 at least).

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply, but I have tried all those filters on the query but I could not get the correct list of items. It would really be appreciated if you can provide an example so that I use the same.Do I have to change Work Item template customisation?

Comment: You should be able to generate a new query. You should probably set yours so that Team Project = YourTeamProject, ReviewedBy = YourReviewer, State = Closed. I believe that this will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you'd want to query the WI history which isn't convenient. You can however create a new field populated automatically and use it in your query.

```
<FieldDefinition name="Ready to test by" refname="Custom.actual.reviewedBy" type="String" reportable="detail">
   <WHENNOTCHANGED field="System.State">
      <READONLY />
   </WHENNOTCHANGED>
   <WHEN field="System.State" value="ReviewCompleted">
      <SERVERDEFAULT from="currentuser" />
   </WHEN>
</FieldDefinition>
```

In my case the field was updated on the assumption that the reviewer is the on changing the state of the WI.